# why `system()` command in R is very memory intensive?

Tags: r

Consider:

```
> setwd('~/tmp/')
> list.files()
[1] "bar"    "foo"    "foobar"
> system("ls")
Warning messages:
1: In system("ls") : system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
2: In system("ls") : error in running command
```

happening when I have close to 9GB RAM showing unused. I am wondering why `system()` function is so memory intensive. If in case you want my `sessionInfo()` then sorry as:

```
sessionInfo()
Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
  cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'uname' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
```

So this is precisely the reason I am posting this question. This memory intensive operation is severely limiting R's ability to connect to any other program. In my perticular case I am trying to use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` which checks presence of `pandoc` using `system('which pandoc')` and eventually fails.

---

sessionInfo using @hrbmstr's suggestion in vanilla mode:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1
```

Comment: what happens if you fire up a command line, vanilla R console and try the same system call to `ls`?

Comment: works fine from vanilla R but not from RStudio. good callout.

Comment: so you can get session info and post that from vanilla? :-) Also: check to make sure no session R data files are being auto-loaded. May want to grab a fresh d/l of RStudio as well in case there's library corruption.

Comment: `R -e "system('ls')"` also works. There is not session R data file loaded. R version and RStudion versions are fairly recent. I can update if you @hrbrmstr think my system config looks outdated.